# How does UIScrollView change its contentOffset when zooming

Tags: uiscrollview, uikit

I'm interested in finding out how UIScrollView changes its contentOffset when zooming an image. It's well known that CAAffineTransform is applied to the view for zooming. However, UIScrollView changes its contentOffset so that the image is centered from the pinch's midpoint during zooming, allowing us to zoom in on a specific point.

A couple of things that I managed to discover are as follows:

The contentOffset obtained after zooming seems to be related to zoomScale, contentSize, and the location of the UIPinchGestureRecognizer (possibly the length or midpoint between the two fingers). However, my attempts to find the suitable function parameters have been unsuccessful.

Perhaps someone knows exactly how this happens?

I was able to approximate the formula based on a few zoomScale, gesture location and contentSize values:

`location.x - scrollView.contentSize.width / scrollView.zoomScale`

However, this won't work if we decide to pan with two fingers, as the location parameters can change abruptly. To handle this, UIScrollView stops recognizing the pinchGesture and prioritizes panGesture.

Comment: Are you asking out of curiosity? Or do you have some specific code you're trying to implement?

Comment: Out of curiosity, I was trying to implement a zoomable photo feature in a UICollectionView cell with the ability to continue zooming and panning. I thought it would be easier to use UIScrollView to avoid implementing rubber banding, scrolling, ect. It turned out writing them manually was easier than trying to zoom and pan UIScrollView using pinch and pan gesture recognizers. Specifically, I couldn't manage to achieve the contentOffset adjustment for centering the photo during zooming. Instead, I achieved it using CGAffineTransform, although I couldn't fully replicate the UIScrollView behaviour